When should .default be used over TRUE in dplyr::case_when
dplyr::case_when has an optional argument, .default, which according to the documentation

.default The value used when all of the LHS inputs return either FALSE or NA.

However, this can also be achieved by setting the last LHS to TRUE.
As such, I am asking when I should use
data %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    a == "Foo" ~ "Bar",
    a == "Baz" ~ "Foo"
    TRUE ~ "Other"
  ))

Instead of
data %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    a == "Foo" ~ "Bar",
    a == "Baz" ~ "Foo",
    .default = "Other"
  ))


.default is the preferred way now. See this for details. "... is a more explicit and readable way"

Your second code doesn’t work. .default is an argument name, not a case expression (in other words, you need to replace ~ by =).

Thank you for the heads-up Konrad, I have corrected the question.

As of now, both options are equivalent. However, the usage of TRUE is not encouraged and meant to be deprecated, due to "unsafe recycling of the LHS inputs". It is still possible to use it, but since dplyr 1.1.0, .default was introduced to replace it. Here is what the changelog says:

case_when() (#5106):
Has a new .default argument that is intended to replace usage of TRUE
~ default_value as a more explicit and readable way to specify a
default value. In the future, we will deprecate the unsafe recycling
of the LHS inputs that allows TRUE ~ to work, so we encourage you to
switch to using .default.


It is curious to me that this is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

Well, the TRUE ~ usage is not in the documentation probably because it is a by-product of the way the function is built under the hood, hence it is not an intended behavior, and not the recommended way to do it.

.default simply is the newer version, and switching is encouraged:
According to the documentation, as of dplyr 1.1.0 case_when() 'has a new .default argument that is intended to replace usage of TRUE ~ default_value as a more explicit and readable way to specify a default value. In the future, we will deprecate the unsafe recycling of the LHS inputs that allows TRUE ~ to work, so we encourage you to switch to using .default.'
